# RAM hot-add HP Proliant - Esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, hotswap

I have to add some RAM to my HP Proliant DL385 g7 and I was wondering if I can hot-add the memory due to some mission critical VMs that I can't move because of lack of hardware. I use ESXi 5.5 as HV. I tried to look around HP support site but I didn't find anything.
Is it possible ? If yes, Is there any risk or precaution I'd take during the operation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 50 of [the manual](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02118792-2%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) says this:

> Installing DIMMs
>   CAUTION: For proper cooling do not operate the server without the access panel, baffles, 
>   expansion slot covers, or blanks installed. If the server supports hot-plug components, 
>   minimize the amount of time the access panel is open.
>
> 1. Power down the server (on page 22).
> 2. Extend the server from the rack (on page 22).
> 3. Remove the access panel (on page 23).
> 4. Remove the air baffle (on page 28).
> 5. Open the DIMM slot latches.
> 6. .... {more steps}

So, no. No hot-add, from my reading of the manual.

Comment: In addition, it specifically says that the PCI riser cage needs to be removed and the server *must* be removed from power to do that.

Answer (score 4):

That functionality needs to be supported both by the hardware platform, and by the OS. In your case, the HP Proliant DL385 g7 manual clearly states that a full power off is needed to install new memory modules, and as such I wouldn't even care to check for ESXI support to the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can hot add ram to the ESXi Guest OS's living on that host.

You will however need to power off the guest during a maintenance period to add RAM to the physical machine.